# Dimensionality reduction for classifying textures with MATLAB

Tags: classification, matlab, dimensionality-reduction, pattern-recognition

I am trying to apply dimensionality reduction on an a set of images (~3000 pixels) using Matlab's Dimensionality Reduction toolbox. However, I know very little about dimension reduction. So I tried several functions by trial and error. PCA returned a matrix with complex numbers, and the others froze MATLAB. Can I get some advice as to which method works good on images? Here are some of the images:

[image]

Comment: PCA is one of the mainstream methods for dimensionality reduction. However, I don't know if you understand what PCA actually does, can you provide your background? I'm not familiar with the Matlab Toolbox for Dimensionality Reduction, but I find it strange that it returns complex numbers...

Comment: My background is computer science. And I trying to write a machine learning program, that can classify patterns in images as either good or bad. But my current problem is with that although the images is relative small, 3 values per pixel case it to be very big set of features. So am passing the matrix of examples (that contains the pixel values) through different dimension reduction methods, but to not avail. (either take too long, or in the case of PCA return a complex values, which cause problems later in the program)

Comment: Now that I recall, it isn't THAT strange to obtain complex values, but as far as I know they usually arise from numerical errors in the calculation of the eigenvalues. Is this the case? If it is, then you can just ignore the imaginary part (they have to be real because the covariance matrix is symmetric).

Comment: Honestly, PCA is a black box to me. All I know is that I give a real matrix, and I get a matrix with some or all values complex. But you  saying I can strip the imaginary components, and it should work just fine?

Comment: If the algorithm works properly (which I expect from a Matlab Toolbox), you can "strip" the imaginary components and leave only the real values. However, I strongly suggest you to learn what PCA actually does before claiming that your results are ok! There are plenty of ways to check that your results are coherent with what you wanted to do if you understand what PCA does.

Comment: I plan to fully learn, but this program is for next week, so time is against me :( So I will have to learn it after. By chance do you know any good resources to learn about PCA?

Comment: From a mathematical perspective, the book "Principal Component Analysis" of I.T. Jolliffe, is excellent and I think the standard book on the subject.

Comment: Learn about PCA [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pca?sort=votes&pagesize=15)

Comment: @Nesp I tried your suggestion and it worked. Thanks you!

Comment: @cubearth glad to see it worked :-)! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the narrower context of facial analysis, your problem is called [eigenface analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface). Since PCA works with vectors, you have to vectorize each image matrix by concatenating all the rows or columns before proceeding. ([Tensor decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_decomposition) has been tried too, but don't worry about that since you're new to PCA.)

The important thing to note is that the images must be standardized---much like a passport photo. If you're trying to compare wildly different images, you'll find that you need a large number of eigenvectors, indicating that dimension reduction is not feasible.

Comment: It's not facial analysis... It's patterns on clothes. Whould PCA work?

Comment: As I think about it, There is quite wide variety. Is there any other recommended methods?

Comment: Please characterize the images in more detail. Can we see them? How many are there?

Comment: I have about 2000 images, and each image is 25 * 125 pixels. And I can't place images (too low rep :( ) but it as varies as much as patterns on clothes/ ties

Comment: Please upload a [contact sheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_sheet) of a representative sample to imgur.com. We can embed it for you. If you are a Windows user you can can use [this](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm).

Comment: A few positive votes on the question will grant cubearth the rep needed to upload those images :-).

Comment: @Emre: Sorry for the long break was stuck in traffic. Ok, this is a small sample set only four, but is should be sufficient to get an idea. http://i.imgur.com/PSpnF.jpg

Comment: @whuber thanks for the excellent suggestion. Can post pictures now :) And this is my first time on cross validate. I frequent stack overflow :)

Comment: I see six images there, not four. Did you make a typo or is there something else going on? Secondly, each image seems to be composed of three horizontally-stacked and identically-sized subimages. Is this a common trait?

Comment: Had to edit and fully explain: yes for both, and here is an example  of a real sample set. Matlab takes three images an form them into one. And I don't actual save the images. I just perform the analysis on the resulting image data. http://imgur.com/DZ1Ea

Comment: You have yet to define your criterion for classifying the patterns as good or bad (see your [comment](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27961/dimension-reduction-on-images-with-matlab#comment52126_27961)). Are the two outer images always similar? You have to provide us with as much information as possible when asking questions because we can leverage it in the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I worked on a 2011 webinar titled "Computer Vision with MATLAB".

The webinar includes a texture classification example that would seem applicable to recognizing patterns in clothing.

You can download all of the code from MATLAB Central

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31152-demos-from-computer-vision-with-matlab-webinar

The example uses a grayscale co-occurence matrix to extract features and then bagged decision trees for a classifier.